# 08 Honda Accord V6 Sedan - Lights on Dashboard

Tags: honda, accord, dashboard-lights

I have a 2008 Honda Accord EX 3.5L V6 with 152k mileage.

Recently, when I started my car the ABS, VSA, EmergencyBrake signs lit up on the dashboard. I turned car off and on, and it remained. I then just left it parked overnight and wanted to see it in the morning, once I started in morning the lights went off, I was relieved. But now the lights came back on again during the evening.

Attaching a picture here - Please ignore the TPMS sign, as this had always been present (unless it’s relevant too)

A few recent event notes: all 4 tires are brand new, installed them like 4-5 months ago. I do have engine oil leak on the vehicle that ruined my alternator so I had to get a new alternator and replaced Valve cover gasket set (engine oil still leaking :(

I recently had mechanic scan it with the lights on dashboard and these are all the codes he found there so many, very concerned and not sure which one to priories in fixing as money is tight right now

[image]

[image: Pic 1 of Scan]
[image: Pic 2 of Scan]

Comment: Have you checked your Honda for any OBDII codes which might be present?

Comment: Issue is the sign came at evening and I only had time in the morning to go to mechanic but by then all the signs disappeared. (I personally do not have the tools for it) Oddly, it seems like morning time no sign, but by evening it comes back

Comment: Usually if the warning lights came on there are history codes that show up on the scan tool. Or you can throw parts at it and that can get expensive. A code could bring you in the direction to clean one of the speed sensors or tone wheel.

Comment: You've got 3 attempted image imbedments, but only 2 image references. Not sure where the 3rd went to.

Comment: Yes I am sorry! This was poor, terrible editing on my part -- I fixed it, there are 3 images now: top is all signs on dashboard 2nd and 3rd images show all the codes found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week I saw an auto electrician and they narrowed the issue down to the ABS Control Module needing replacement due to the VSA solenoid codes.

I got the part from eBay and installed it yesterday, so far it seems like the sign is gone, not trying to jinx it but it seems the issue for me was the ABS Control Module.

Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do a Ac ripple test on my alternator diodes. Connect voltmeter to alternator Battery post and a known good ground.Set on AC scale and run engine at 2000 Rpm with all accessories on. Your maximum allowable AC voltage is 300 millivolts ie .3 volts.if this test exceeds 300 millivolts, I would replace the alternator. Better yet, if you can duplicate the symptom, unplug the electrical connector on the alternator and take it for a test drive. See if problem goes away with the alternator unplugged. You say you have recently replaced your alternator. Did you have any of these issues before you replaced the alternator?

Comment: I take it you are suggesting, if this test fails, the OP should then replace the alternator? Could the OP also take the alternator somewhere and figure out the same results?

Comment: Test is from Engine Performance Diagnostics by Paul Danner . AC ripple test. pg. 28

Comment: That's great information. Not really what I was getting at, though. I'm trying to get you to flesh out your answer a little bit so the OP understands all options and conclusions considering follow-on actions. *What should I do if I get this answer from the test?* Remember, we want to give information to the masses, not just one person.

Comment: If I read 300 millivolts or more, I would replace alternator. If you can duplicate problem, unplug the alternator, drive the car and see if the problem goes away with alternator unplugged.

Comment: Please click the edit button and present further information into the body of your answer.

Comment: My alternator is brand new Duralast from Autozone installed very recently (my bad for not mentioning in my post I will edit), I don’t think it’s the issue but then again my VVT has leaks and it’s been dripping into my alternator, im gonna fix the leak tomorrow

Comment: You have a valid point, I did not have any of these signs prior to changing my alternator, it occurred a few days after my new alternator was installed. I was forced to change the alternator because the oil leak from the VVT above it killed my alternator, and even the new alternator definitely got some drops of oil leak, before I was able to change the VVT.